# Есть ли движок на GLUT-е?

Tags: c++, c, glut

Видел программу звёздная система на GLUT написанная "процедурным" методом.

НО ни одного движка я на нём не видел ! Почему так?

У меня есть несколько предположений, первое наверняка что то есть но по сути, не распространённое (либо я не умею искать). Либо просто что-то не ладное в GLUT королевстве (многопоточность не поддерживается и т.д.(не поддерживаются основные треуголы программирования)).

Comment: Ну как минимум GLUT автоматически означает отсутствие поддержки DirectX и Vulkan, что сразу ставит крест на не-ПК устройствах

Comment: OpenGL - не то же самое, что GLUT. С OpenGL можно работать из без GLUT. (Например через SDL2, на котором движков хватает.)

Comment: Что там изучать? GLUT это достаточно ограниченная вспомогательная библиотека. Если нужна простой фундамент, который возьмет на себя взаимодействие с системой, то лучше выбрать что-то поновее, тот же SDL или SFML.

Comment: `DirectX ... не для солидных и себя уважающих мужчин` — а ничего, что OpenGL (aka Glide) — это отражение архитектуры видеокарт Voodoo (константы GL_* — это точные номера их внутренних регистров), которые работали по совершенно другому принципу, чем нынешние карты? Сейчас никто не ставит несколько узкоспециализированных однозадачных чипов, настраиваемых через регистры (две микросхемы для трансформации вершин, четыре для наложения текстур). Вместо этого уже двадцать лет используются универсальный векторный процессор и общая память.

Comment: Так что OpenGL — это дань однопоточной конвейерной совместимости, не дающая оптимизироваться под современные видеокарты. Для одних задач этого хватает, для других нет.

Comment: `А вулкан чтоб треугол нарисовать простейший, надо написать 7803 страницы рукописного тексту` — ну так низкоуровневое API, отражающее все нюансы строение современных видеокарт. Вулкан создан не для вывода треугольников, а для выжимания из железа всех возможных соков. Для рядового применения это вообще не надо, а потому достаточно OpenGL и DirectX. И да, ходят слухи, что Вулкан (он же Mantle) вообще из консолей вышел, а там своя атмосфера.

Comment: Пожалуйста. И ещё. Откуда такая ненависть к D3D API? "Билли насильник" — это всего лишь гендир, к тому же давно отошедший от дел. Так что ваша ненависть, по сути, направлена на ядерных разработчиков. И если в пользовательском WinAPI действительно тихий ужас из-за совместимости с *крайне косячными решениями* в раннем Windows, то в ядерном хозяйстве всё стройно и логично.

Comment: "Также не могу понять почему в "беседках" совершенно нету общения по графическим инструментам и оболочкам" - если звезды зажигают, значит это кому-то нужно. Если комнату не создали, значит никому не было нужно. Вы можете ее сами создать (в чатах внизу есть кнопка "create a new room", создавать чаты можно [начиная со 100 баллов репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms)).

Comment: К слову, с чем я совершенно согласен, так это с очень удобной модульной структурой OpenGL и Vulkan, при которой новая возможность сначала публично обкатывается каким-то производителем в виде вендорного модуля, а потом, после исправления всех вплывших на практике косяков, включается в стандарт. Учитывая, что конкретная версия GL — это всего лишь список гарантированно поддерживаемых модулей, получается обалденно удобная система. D3D в этом плане жёсткий как бревно.

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev по тому что  DirectX "грязного били" не поддерживается в linux-ах  :3

Comment: `не поддерживается в linux-ах` — это да, к несчастью есть такое. Реквестирую D3D-подобную обёртку над Вулканом, чтобы им было не так больно пользоваться.

Comment: Не думаю, что это как-либо существенно влияло на сложность написания 3д игры

Comment: @ VTT честно на меня влияет , к примеру glut намного лоучше чем чистый OpenGL

Comment: @HolyBlackCat _(Например через SDL2, на котором движков хватает.)_ увы пока только Urho3D нашёл на нём, есть ещё ZEngine  но но только 2D

Comment: На нем Source Engine, CryEngine, ... Если верить википедии: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_games_using_SDL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Увы на сейчашний момент, "движка" на базе GLUT-a не имеем (21.10.2019)